# Delay in I2S audio from SD card

Tags: arduino, audio, esp32, sd, i2s

This question was already asked on specific arduino forum but I didnt recieve any answers and views were very limited hence I am posting here for better reach.

I am trying to play wav file saved in SD card using ESP32 dev module. For output I am using MAX98357A amplifier module and using I2S.

Everything works fine except I get delay in output of around 4 to 5 seconds and because of that I cant tell when audio was completed so that I can close that I2S port.

I have added delay of 4 seconds just to complete the audio play than I am closing I2S port and I dont want to add random delays like this.

Question is, Why I am gtting delay at the first place ? Is there any way to know that audio play was completed ?? My "i2s_read_len" is of 16384. Is it too large or something ? File size is of 1MB.

Thank you. Please ask if need more information.

```
 if (!digitalRead(15)) {  // Playing
    digitalWrite(2, 1);
    file = SD.open(filename, FILE_READ);
    if (!file) return;

    byte header[headerSize];
    file.read(header, headerSize);
    WAV_RECORD_SIZE = (header[43] << 24) + (header[42] << 16) + (header[41] << 8) + header[40];
    // WAV_RECORD_SIZE = file.size();
    Serial.print("record size : ");
    Serial.println(WAV_RECORD_SIZE);

    i2sInit_tx();

    unsigned long i2s_wr_size = 0;
    size_t bytes_written;
    uint8_t* sd_read_buff = (uint8_t*)calloc(i2s_read_len, sizeof(uint8_t));

    Serial.println(" *** Playing Start *** ");

    while (i2s_wr_size < WAV_RECORD_SIZE) {
      file.read((uint8_t*)sd_read_buff, i2s_read_len);
      i2s_write(I2S_PORT_TX, (void*)sd_read_buff, i2s_read_len, &bytes_written, portMAX_DELAY);
      i2s_wr_size += i2s_read_len;
      ets_printf(" %u", i2s_wr_size * 100 / WAV_RECORD_SIZE); // show process percentage
    }
    ets_printf("\n");

    file.close();
    free(sd_read_buff);
    sd_read_buff = NULL;
    delay(4000);
    // i2s_zero_dma_buffer(I2S_PORT_TX);
    i2s_driver_uninstall(I2S_PORT_TX);
    digitalWrite(2, 0);
    Serial.println("Audio play completed");
  }
  delay(10);
```

Below is I2S config

```
i2s_config_t i2s_config = {
    .mode = (i2s_mode_t)(I2S_MODE_MASTER | I2S_MODE_RX),
    .sample_rate = I2S_SAMPLE_RATE, // 16000
    .bits_per_sample = i2s_bits_per_sample_t(I2S_SAMPLE_BITS), // 16
    .channel_format = I2S_CHANNEL_FMT_ONLY_LEFT,
    .communication_format = i2s_comm_format_t(I2S_COMM_FORMAT_I2S | I2S_COMM_FORMAT_I2S_MSB),
    .intr_alloc_flags = 0,
    .dma_buf_count = 64,
    .dma_buf_len = 1024,
    .use_apll = 1
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get a 4 second delay because you have a 4 second buffer.

You have 64 buffers of length 1024.

Assuming they are samples, that's 65536 samples of buffers.

You sampling rate is 16000 samples per second.

65536 / 16000 is exactly 4096 milliseconds, or 4.096 seconds.

Comment: Try 20 buffers, then 10, 2, and if that works, try 1 (at some point it will become choppy / distorted.)  The lower the buffers, the lower the latency; but the more timing-critical the I2S routines become.  Add a long routine later, and the buffers may have to be increased again.

Comment: Thank you. That does justify things clearly. I will play around with those number a bit to get optimum output. However, can you tell me how can I know when dma buffer is empty ??